# Resolution x Building Problems Unity3D

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, resolution, screen-resolution

I find 2 people with the same problem, but all answers didn't work. So I'll try asking myself and let see what we will have, already thanks!!!

I used to use the version `4.6.1`.

The project is basic some scenes, and the main scene we usually use the command 
`Screen.setResolution(1024,768,true)` to "fit" to all resolutions and be full screen.

In the version `4.6.1`, it worked fine for a while then not anymore, but for the new project we used the `4.6.4`, and when we build the `.exe`, it don't really fit to the screen (1600x900) it take place in the middle of the screen with a black bar in each side.

We tried open a old project because we thought it could be some setting we were using wrongly, but with the same settings from the old (which is working) still has the problem!!!

We think it might be some windows update, because it is not changing windows native resolution , make any sense?

It only works on `4.0.17b (beta version)`.

Is there anything we could do?

Comment: Could you provide links to the 2 people with the same problem? This sounds like something to take up with the vendor's product support.

Comment: These are the ones i remember but i found at least one more person who has simillar problem.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/2qj9ak/vertical_black_bars_in_nonnative_resolutions/

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/516517/why-doesnt-standalone-build-resolution-settings-af.html

I found people having the opposite problem, they want the black bar, but here we cant have it, because the older projects the client saw it with no bars... So I really wonder why that happened, and if it is on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

See [patch notes for Unity 4.6.1](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-4.6.1):

> DX9: Add black bars in fullscreen mode to maintain aspect ratio.

This may have worked for you, before, depending on graphics settings and drivers.

In any case, you should generally assign a resolution that's appropriate for your monitor's aspect ratio. To calculate the aspect ratio of any given resolution, divide width by height, which you can read from `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`, or use one of the recommended resolutions from [`Screen.resolutions`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-resolutions.html).

Comment: But when i set others resolutions instead of 1024x768, the itens on the game just get messed up, so its the way we here find to do the game once and fit all devices with all kinds of resolution, so that was really hepfull for us, and another point we need to keep that way, because the client saw it that way